# Javascript: Defining an array with shortcuts

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I don't really know how to ask this and maybe that is why I can't properly find the answer to this problem.

So I have a very long list of numbers and I intend to put them in an array.

```
154,153,152,148,145,133,132,131,130,...,6,5,4,1 (You get the idea.)
```

The problem is that I'm lazy and don't want to type out all the numbers out into this "initial" array. (Notice that there are sequential strings of numbers in the list.)

I thought I could do something like this:

```
var array = [154:152,148,133:130,...,6:4,1];
```

Which would yield something like this for `array`:

```
[154,153,152,148,133,132,131,130,...,6,5,4,1]
```

I know I can do a loop to fill these in. But the tricky parts are the "breaks" in the sequence.

Any help or obvious solution that I missed would be appreciated.

(This is for some code in google spreadsheets, which uses javascript as a basis.)

Comment: What is your initial input format of the list of numbers?

Comment: Like it is shown in my post. Just numbers that need to be put into an array.

Comment: I get that part, I'm wondering if the list is predefined or if you are starting with nothing

Comment: It will be written in the code itself before running. No importing in data which contains the numbers.

Comment: Yes, it is predefined, in the sense that I know what to put into the array. Only thing is that it is really long. This has to do with specific columns in google spreadsheet that need to be edited. And I want to automate it.

Comment: I think you are attacking this from the wrong angle – if you want to prevent typing all those numbers, you should find a way to import the data if it already exists somewhere else. After all, this is why we have computers and interoperability.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to write shorthand for arrays without overriding the array implementation in javascript or coming up with your own datatype to read it.

Comment: The thing is I'm not manipulating any data. I'm manipulating certain columns in a google spreadsheet. In short, I just want to change the widths of certain columns. So I was planning on using a loop that uses  an array which has the columns' number as elements.

I guess, like you guys are saying, that it can't be done natively by javascript. (Though it would be useful.)

I think C5H8NNaO4 answer helps me achieve this the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do that natively.
You could however write a simple helper function which does it for you.

```
function createRange(arr) {
    var result = [], //The resulting array
        range;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {//Iterate over the array
        if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) { //If we find another array 
            range = arr [i];
            for (var j=range [0]; j <= range [1]; j++) {//increase its first element until it's equal the second
                result.push(j); //add the number to the resulting array
            }
        } else { //If it's a number
            result.push(arr[i]); //put it in the resulting array
        }
    }
    return result; //return the array containing the range
}

createRange ([[1,5],10,[15,20]]) //[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

Heres a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Glutamat/53f3L/3) as well

Answer (score 0):

what do you think about this?

```
var a = ['154:152','148','133:130','6:4','1'];
var array = [];
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
  var b = a[i];
  b = b.split(':');
  if (b.length == 2)
  {
    for (var j = b[0]; j > b[1]-1; j--)
    {
      array[array.length] = j;
      document.write(j);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    array[array.length] = b[0];
      document.write(b[0]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I would choose this as a second answer if I could. (I tried to, but it wouldn't let me.)

Comment: :) thanks

if you mark my answer useful that gives me almost the same amount of points ;)

Comment: How do I do that..? I don't see an option like that. http://www.clipular.com/c/5385305997705216.png?k=mxq7eavjB1uoN6emxH63LYx4J-o

Comment: Never mind. I see that you mean that I upvote you. I tried that too. I don't have enough reputation points. Soon as I get enough I'll come back and do it. :)